# MySQL Identifier Question

Tags: mysql

From the mysql certification guide's example questions ...

**question**

```
Will the following SQL statement succeed or result in an error? Assume that the table to be created doesn't already exist.

CREATE TABLE MD5 (id INT);
```

**answer**

```
The statement results in an error if the IGNORE_SPACE SQL mode is enabled. In that case, all function names become reserved words and the statement would return an error because MD5 is a function name.

If the IGNORE_SPACE SQL mode is not enabled, the statement succeeds:

mysql> CREATE TABLE MD5 (id INT);
Query OK, 0 rows affected


Note that the IGNORE_SPACE SQL mode is part of the ANSI SQL mode.
```

Why do they talk about spaces? Anyone got any idea? What will be the correct answer? It fails because a function is a reserved word?  Will it succeed when quoted, eg. with backtick... right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`IGNORE_SPACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ignore_space) mode allows spaces between function name and the following parenthesis. If it's enabled, all function names become reserved words because it becomes impossible for MySQL to determine whether you're calling a function or declaring (using) an identifier.

Hence, if it's enabled, your `CREATE TABLE` will fail and the following:

```
SELECT MD5 (some_column) FROM some_table
```

will work. If `IGNORE_SPACE` is disabled, the opposite will happen (`CREATE TABLE` will work and above `SELECT` will not because there is a space between function name and the parenthesis).

Answer (score 0):

[`IGNORE_SPACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ignore_space) will ignore spaces between a potential function name and `(`

[Mysql's manual page on function resolution explains it all](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/function-resolution.html), but here's the short version:

```
SELECT md5(colum1) FROM table;
```

Applies the md5 function to colum1.

```
 SELECT md5 (colum1) FROM table;
```

Applies the md5 function, if `IGNORE_SPACE` is enabled, to colum1.

If `IGNORE_SPACE` is off, "md5 (" is not treated as a function call, because there's a space in there.

Putting the backticks makes Mysql not thing the word is a function name but some database, table, column etc identifier.